Ionic : pb solving dependecies
Context:
Angular version (if applicable)
Relevant dependencies listed in your package.json file (especially @angular/* packages, ng2-charts, and @ionic/angular-server)
Any specific steps you've taken before encountering the error
Questions:
How can I resolve this conflicting peer dependency issue?
Are there specific version combinations of @angular/core and @angular/animations that are known to work well together?
Is there a way to force-install the desired versions, even if it might lead to compatibility issues (not recommended unless absolutely necessary)?
npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE`
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/animations@15.2.10
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@15.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"^15.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from @angular/cdk@15.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"^15.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@">=14.0.0" from ng2-charts@4.1.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/ng2-charts
npm ERR!       ng2-charts@"^4.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   10 more (@angular/common, @angular/compiler, @angular/forms, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"15.2.10" from @angular/animations@15.2.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   peer @angular/animations@"15.2.10" from @angular/platform-server@15.2.10
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/platform-server
npm ERR!     peerOptional @angular/platform-server@"^15.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.0.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (@ionic/angular-server)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@15.2.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"15.2.10" from @angular/animations@15.2.10
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     peer @angular/animations@"15.2.10" from @angular/platform-server@15.2.10
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-server
npm ERR!       peerOptional @angular/platform-server@"^15.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.0.4
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!         dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@ionic/angular-server)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry```


i am trying to install npm modules with npm install to build android app

